# How to display related products through pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to display related item which is in same category.

Here is my 3 table  structure

**food item table**
:
"food_item_id",

"name" ,

"image"  ,

**food item category table  :**

"food_item_category_id"

"name"

**pivot table**

id,

food_item_id

food_item_category_id

**FooItem model:**

```
public function foodItemCategory() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(FoodItemCategory::class, 'food_items_have_categories', 'food_item_id', 'food_item_category_id')
        ->withPivot('food_item_id', 'food_item_category_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Food Category Model:**

```
 public function foodItem() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(FoodItem::class, 'food_items_have_categories', 'food_item_category_id', 'food_item_id')
        ->withPivot('food_item_id', 'food_item_category_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I want to get all food items from a specific category. Suppose a user clicks on a food item which Id is 1 and It is belongs to category ID 2. Now I want to show more food items which is in the category ID 2. I want to display that in my view blade.
Now, how can I display the related products in view which is in the same category?

Comment: Hi. You have pivot table so one Item can have zero or many categories. Which one you want to select? Does it matter or you just want any item with categories of this item?

Comment: @ Mohammad Mirsafaei, Suppose I have food items which ID Is 1,2,3,4,5. Now I  select item ID 1 and it is in a category is 3. In category ID 3 may have more items such as food item ID 3,5 or not, I want to display that if food item has same category ID. When a user click food item ID 1, it will show item ID 1 detail and also show in below Item ID 3, 5 detail becasue item 1,3,5 have same category ID 3

Comment: @Prince Item may have many categories right like A, B & C ? then the related items will show from category A B & C or there is any other case, Also you have many to many mapping and `withPivot` clause is redundant because it hold the foreign keys which are already defined in your `belongsToMany` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your relation is many to many, you can do this:

```
$food = FoodItem::find(1);
$categories = $food->foodItemCategory;
$items = [];
foreach($categories as $category) {
   $items[$category->id] = $category->foodItem;
}
```

then you can pass `$items` to your blade template.

Comment: Thanks. Its worked.  But what if I want to display all items except this FoodItem::find(1) ??

Comment: Your welcome. You can do this: `$items[$category->id] = $category->foodItem()->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->id != $food->id;})->toArray()`